# Wikidata/Wikidata-Toolkit Getting entities by SPARQL query (#362)

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-query-service

I am trying to understand the above issue, but still unclear about the exact requirement in the issue. Can you please describe it once again in detail?

What I can figure out is :-

1. This query is working on Wikidata Query Service platform

   SELECT ?station WHERE {
   ?station wdt:P954 ?ibnr.
   FILTER regex(?ibnr,"^80","i")
   }
2. So is this -

   SELECT ?station ?stationLabel WHERE {
   ?station wdt:P954 ?ibnr
   FILTER regex(?ibnr,"^80","i")
   SERVICE wikibase:label {               # ... include the labels
   bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en"
   }
   }

But, this also gives the labels associated with the station names which are extracted using Service keyword
(These two are the ones you mentioned in the comments. )
So, what exactly is the aim of the API? since the standard SPARQL queries are also working on that Wikidata Query Service platform. If possible also mention the files I should go through for the same.